# What is the Standard Paper Size in Pageformat at a Java Printing job.

Tags: java, printing

im working on an application which should print some data. I did go through tutorials and so. 
No im at the point where im defining the size of the printable area.

I entered the values and it worked. 
then i tried to do it without it and it got the same values i need.

Now here is my question, where gets the pageformat the information how big the size is (as in the print()) (the standard size not a custom size) ?

[This is the tutorial i followed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [getPrinterJob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#getPrinterJob--) method description, Java uses the page settings for your default printer in your operating system.

Comment: ah thanks :D Creates and returns a PrinterJob which is initially associated with the default printer. so it gets all from the default printer ;)